# Using react useEffect hook

Tags: reactjs

I'm using React useEffect hook for getting data and display the loading indicator but my loading is not working.

Heres the useEffect Hook code:

```
useEffect(() => {
  fetchEvents();
}, []);
```

`fetchEvents` function code:

```
const fetchEvents = () => {
  setLoading(true);
  const requestBody = {
    query: `
              query {
                events {
                  _id
                  title
                  description
                  price
                  date
                  creator {
                    _id
                    email
                  }
                }
              }
            `
  };

  fetch("http://localhost:5000/graphql", {
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
      },
      method: "POST",
      body: JSON.stringify(requestBody)
    })
    .then(res => {
      if (res.status !== 200 && res.status !== 201) {
        throw new Error("Failed");
      }
      return res.json();
    })
    .then(resData => {
      const events = resData.data.events;
      setEvents(events);
      setLoading(false);
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.log(err);
      setLoading(false);
    });
};
```

Comment: What do you mean by your loading is not working?

Comment: So what does the rendering look like?

Comment: its not showing on the page

Comment: its just fetch the data without showing the loading

Comment: you should show us more than just the `fetchData` function

Comment: @Victor like what exactly?

Comment: are the `loading` and `events` defined using `useState`?

Comment: yes they are set by usestate

const [events, setEvents] = useState([]);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);

Comment: Can you make a fiddle, or show us the whole component? That way we can better help answer your question

Comment: @Tayab and you are certain the data just isn't loading _really_ quickly? Have you done simple things like use logs to determine code coverage?

Answer (score 0):

You should give more info but here an example for you:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { Spinner } from 'react-bootstrap';

const MyComponent = () => {
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    setIsLoading(true);
    fetch('/data/endpoint')
      .then((res) => res.json)
      .then((response) => {
        setData([...response]);
        setIsLoading(false);
      });
  }, []);

  return isLoading ? (
    <Spinner />
  ) : (
    <ol>
      data.map(items => <li>{items.label}</li>);
    </ol>
  );
};
```

Answer (score -1):

The first parameter of `useEffect` (the function) is only called if one object of the second parameter (the list) is modified. If the list is empty, it never happens.

You could remove the second parameter to apply the function `fetchEvents` at each update or you could use any constant to run `fetchEvents` only once.

Comment: that's plain wrong, if the dependency list (seocnd parameter) is empty, the useEffect first parameter is called exactly once (on component mount) and not never!